# SOQL to return Account.Name from sObject Opportunity

Tags: apex

I have a extension for a standard controller which is used to create an Opportunity record from the inputs of a Visualforce page. I am trying to assign the Opportunity name field to the value of the Account Name which the Opportunity is under.

When I make the statement prior to the insert DML like this: `o.Name = closedWonNBOpp.AccountId`, the Opportunity Name of the newly created Opportunity is the Id of the Account. So then I go one step further: `o.Name = closedWonNBOpp.Account.Name` but to no avail.

In workbench, a sOQL like `SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity` returns a success but a SOQL like `SELECT Account.Name FROM Opportunity` returns a failure. And I don't see why?

I have tested plenty of ways to try and get around this - for example, using String.valueOf() etc but all to no avail. How can I assign the value of the o.Name field to be the Account Name that the Opportunity belongs to?

Thanks,

```
public with sharing class closedWonNewBusinessRedirect{

    // property
    public Opportunity closedWonNBOpp {get; set;}

    // constructor for extension
    public closedWonNewBusinessRedirect(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        closedWonNBOpp = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference createOppAndRedirect(){
        try{
            Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
            o.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('New Business').getRecordTypeId();
            o.AccountId = closedWonNBOpp.AccountId;
            o.OwnerId = UserInfo.getuserId();
            String ownerName = UserInfo.getUserName();
            o.CloseDate = closedWonNBOpp.CloseDate;
            o.Billing_Effective_Date__c = closedWonNBOpp.Billing_Effective_Date__c;
            o.Amount = closedWonNBOpp.Amount;
            o.StageName = closedWonNBOpp.StageName;
            o.Probability = closedWonNBOpp.Probability;
            o.Description = closedWonNBOpp.Description;
            o.Name = closedWonNBOpp.Account.Name;
            insert o;
             } catch (DmlException e){
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred from the closedWonNewBusinessRedirect.apxc: ' + e.getMessage());
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'There has been an error with this page. Please email ahitchings@tullettprebon.com to log this issue.'));
        }
```

Comment: I do not see any SOQL to get the account.name in your controller. [select account.name from opportunity] does work. Having said that you can do o.AccountId = closedWonNBOpp.AccountId. getRecord() as per docs will only have access to the fields of the object referenced on the vf page based on the ID

Comment: @Rao - thanks, once I changed my settings in workbench to 'allows soql parent relationship queries' then I was able to use the soql: select account.name from opportunity (whereas before that option unchecked, it would return an error). I can't believe that I cannot get the account.name from an opportunity...

Comment: you can get the account name from the oppty but in this particular case you have to query the account name. get record as i previously stated does not have related object fields, it has access only to the object in context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign o.name to be the value of the account name simply add the below line in your try block

o.name = [select name from account where id=:closedWonNBOpp.accountId].name;

**Update**:

The above solution I provided works but not the most efficient/ best practice way to go, researching more you can actually do this without wasting a SOQL query.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm

All you have to do is instruct the standard controller to add the account.name as part of fields to be retrieved when fetching the data using getRecord() method

**Change this part to :**

```
 // constructor for extension
    public closedWonNewBusinessRedirect(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        controller.addFields(new string[]{'Account.name'});
        closedWonNBOpp = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
    }
```

In your VF page

Comment: perfect, it works! Thanks a lot - I see how that works now.

Comment: @AndyHitchings Please look at the update I posted

Comment: thank you, can you advise how I can access the String from addFields? I have tried: String accountName = closedWonNBOpp.Account.Name; but this returns null. Thanks

Comment: @AndyHitchings are you passing an ID to the VF page or is it plain /apex/yourvfpagename

Comment: it is a plain /apex/vfpagename. Thanks

Comment: getrecord() populates data based on what has been filled on the vf page, I assumed you passed an oppty Id to the page, addfield creates a reference to the fieldsnames which in your case is not applicable. You will have to resort to the query approach since you do not have related info(account) available